# C# - FilesystemWatcher, MDB files and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

I am a PHP developer, and I need to import some files from a Windows Machine, which have an really old application that Generate .MDB (Access Database) twice a day, with many useful information. I need to query these MDB files, as soon as they got created in the filesystem, querying the data and importing in an existing MySQL database. All this information should be available in Intranet, developed in PHP, linux.

Unfortunately, there is no free ODBC Driver for Linux, so I decided to use C#, creating an application to perform the needed.

Can someone give me some advice in what I have to read?

So far, I know that I have to use FilesystemWatcher, from System.IO, in order to get the Created Event.

Currently I tested some connection with the MDB database, but I am not able to retrieve all tables from it.

I am actually querying:

```
select * FROM [Abertura Caixa];
```

Is there any way to query many different tables?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\projects\\letseatdev\\public\\fechamentos\\LJ00004CX001DT03122016No0762Per02.mdb");
                conn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM [Abertura Caixa];", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Abertura Caixa");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Caixa Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Cartões Ocorrencias Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Cartões Pagos Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Clientes");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "CombosVendidos Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "CombosVendidosItens Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Comissões Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Conciliação de Caixa Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Conta Corrente Assinada");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Contas Canceladas Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Contas Reimpressas Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Contra Vales Emitidos Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "CupomReferenciado");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Descontos Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Devolucao");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "ECF Log Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Fechamento de Caixa");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Fidelidade Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Giro de Mesas Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Inventario Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Invetario_SPED");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Mapa Resumo Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "NF_Referenciada");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Pedidos Cancelados Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "PedidosOnline Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Penduras");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Produto Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sangrias Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Totalizador Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Transferencia Estoques");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Transferencia Mesa Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Transporte");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "ComissoesCanceladas Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "ECF Item Log Local");
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Livros Fiscais");
                myDataAdapter.Dispose();
                conn.Close();

                int i = 0;

                for (i = 0; i <= myDataSet.Tables["ECF Item Log Local"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myDataSet.Tables["ECF Item Log Local"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1 -

New Code. It keep retrieving from table "Abertura Caixa":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\projects\\letseatdev\\public\\fechamentos\\LJ00004CX001DT03122016No0762Per02.mdb");
                conn.Open();



                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM [Abertura Caixa];", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Abertura Caixa");

                OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM [Caixa Local];", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                myDataAdapter2.Fill(myDataSet, "Abertura Caixa");

                OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM [ECF Item Log Local];", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                myDataAdapter3.Fill(myDataSet, "ECF Item Log Local");

                conn.Close();

                int i = 0;

                for (i = 0; i <= myDataSet.Tables["ECF Item Log Local"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myDataSet.Tables["ECF Item Log Local"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The adapter executes only the command that you have passed in its constructor. Cannot fill the other tables if you don't add the correct command text for each table. A probably faster and simpler approach is to use a list of all the table names you are interested to retrieve, loop over this list creating a SELECT * command and then use directly the command to load a DataTable. After that you could add the DataTable to the collection stored by a DataSet.

```
List<string> tables = new List<string>()
{ 
  "Abertura Caixa", "Caixa Local", "Cartões Ocorrencias Local",
  "Cartões Pagos Local", ..... all other table names... 
};

conn = new OleDbConnection("......");
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
foreach(string table in tables)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(table);
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am now getting error because of the TableName spaces, so I did:  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM \"" + table + "\";", conn); and still not working =/

Comment: I should use [] instead. OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "];", conn);

Comment: Oh yes, those names contain spaces.. You need square brackets around their names